# What is the derivative of $f(x)=-e^x$?

Tags: calculus

I have this function:

$y= (15 - e^{3t})$

I am pretty sure the derivative of that function, using Chain Rule, is

$y'= -e^{3t}*3$

But why is it negative again? Maybe I'm just having a brainfart... but why is it negative? The only rule I know is that the derivative of $y = e^x$ is $e^x$. So given that rule, what is the derivative of $-e^x$?

I remember my limit rules a bit like...

$\lim_{x \to 2} -2x$

$= -1 \lim_{x \to 2} 2x$

$= -4$

Does that concept apply here?

Comment: You seem to have $e^{et}$ above, while $e^{3t}$ seems to appear in the succeeding lines. Then, you are asking about $e^{-x}$. Please tells us what you would like clarified, and if possible, either edit the rest out or arrange the questions in a more orderly fashion.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, @Jwan622  it all is consistent now.  Thanks for your edits.

Comment: @Jwan622 Thank you for your edit. Also +1 for the improvement.

Answer (score 6):

We have:

$y = (15 - e^{3t})$

$$y' = \underbrace{0}_{\frac d{dt}(15)} - (\underbrace{3}_{\frac d{dt}(3t)}\cdot e^{3t})$$

You see, $3$ in $3t$ is just a constant.  When, via the chain rule, we take $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(15- e^{3t}\right) = \frac d{dt} (15) -\frac d{dt}(e^{3t}) =0 - \left(e^{3t} \cdot \frac d{dt} (3t)\right) = - \left( e^{3t}\cdot 3\right) = -3\left( e^{3t}\right)$$

In either case, either $15- e^{et}$ or $15-e^{3t}$, or $15-e^{1231791\, t}$, or $15 - e^{kt}$ where $k$ is any real constant, we get that the derivative is equal to $-k\cdot e^{kt}$, in each case, by the chain rule.

---

$−e^{kt}$ is to be treated just as we would treat $−(e^{kt}).$ It is **not** to be taken to mean $(−e)^{kt}$. That's a major difference.

In general, when we have $e^{f(x)}$, the derivative is $e^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$

Comment: I assumed e^{et} was a typo for e^{3t}, but maybe not...

Comment: Yes, well, assuming the first line wasn't a typo in the OP.

Comment: $e^a \cdot e^b = e^{a+b}$

Comment: In any case, Jwan622, $-e^{kt}$ is to be parsed as $-\left(e^{kt}\right)$.  It is **not to be taken to mean** $(-e)^{kt}$ in this case.  It is the $e$ that is raised to the exponent $et$ or $3t$ or $kt$ (whatever constant you want to use in the exponent).  So  $y' = -e^{kt}\cdot k = -k\left(e^{kt}\right) =  - \left(k \cdot e^{kt}\right)$

Comment: Fixed my post I think

Comment: Well, I wrote the answer in terms of $15 - e^{3k}$ now, but the generalization, using k to mean any real number whatsoever, gives us similar results.

Comment: But what rule governs the derivative of $-(e^{kt})$ is my question. What rule is that? Is there a rule that says take the derivative of everything but the negative and then just put the negative sign at the beginning?? Or are we using an application of the power rule and finding the derivative of $(-1)*e^{kt}$

Comment: It is the chain rule:  Whenever we have $e^{f(t)}$ or $-e^{f(t)}$, the respective derivatives are going to be $e^{f(t)} \cdot f'(t)$, or $- e^{f(t)} \cdot f'(t)$.  Yes, you can consider $(-1)$ as a constant prior to the function $e^{kt}$.  But the derivative is $$(-1) e^{kt}\cdot \underbrace{k}_{\frac d{dt}(kt)}= (-1)k\cdot e^{kt} = -ke^{kt}$$

Comment: Let me know if that helps, Jwan622.  I need to get some sleep now, but I'll check in tomorrow morning, okay?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if the derivative of $f(x)$ is $f'(x)$, then the derivative of $-f(x)$ is $-f'(x)$; also, the derivative of $C-f(x)$, for any constant $C$, is $-f'(x)$.

So if we let $C = 15$, and $f(x) = e^{3x}$, then $f'(x) = 3e^{3x}$, and

$$
\frac{d}{dx} 15-e^{3x} = -3e^{3x}
$$

Comment: Is this because we can use the product rule when calculating the derivative of -1 and e^x ?

Comment: I suppose you could think of it that way, but to me, it seems more basic to recognize that differentiation is a linear operator, so the derivative of $kf(x)$, where $k$ is some constant, is $kf'(x)$, where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Is your function $(15-e^{3t})$? Because you said you have a function $(15-e^{et})$ but you have derivative $-e^{3t}$. If your fcn is  $(15-e^{3t})$, 
Its derivative is  $-e^{3t}$ *3. Dont forget that  $e$ is negative so you get a negative answer

Comment: But is that how you take the derivative of that multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of 15 is 0 and you are left with finding the derivative of -e^3t, imagine the equation like this
(-1)*(e^3t) and now simply factor out the (-1) constant, apply derivative and factor the constant back in.